# Microsoft teams add custom text handlers

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to add custom text handlers in Microsoft Teams? For example when I Type `@` in chat then I can pick from users. Similarly  want to bind a key to another option when I can lookup something from our web service and add it to the chat window. Following documentation describes how to write connectors for Microsoft Teams but doesn't say anything about what I am looking for.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors

Comment: Down voters at least put some effort to explain what's wrong with this. If you think I am not doing something right here then you guys are doing it worst as nobody knows what's going on in mind of your that's causing you grief.

Answer (score 2):

[mayank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043683/mayank), the closest direct thing to what you want is what we call compose extensions. That feature is in preview and is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/composeextensions). That will let you call a web service and interactively show results from a search in a popup list, not unlike our Giphy integration.

Under the covers, it's a special kind of bot as [mark-lafleur-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur-msft) described. With a bot, the difference is that the results from the web service don't appear in a popup window.

Last but not least, the simplest way of all, if all you want to do is execute commands from within a channel and return information, is to create a "Custom Bot" (similar to an "Outgoing webhook" in Slack). Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing here is what [Bots in Teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/bots) are intended for. Once built, you simply reference the bot by `@botname` and your query: `@botname look up something from web service`.